Getting Errors with Loop in Stored Procedure in Snowflake
I have a procedure in snowflake which creates backups of Databases by cloning them.
There is a problem with this procedure in that it also clones the masking policies and row policies from the reference database to the cloned database.
I am trying to add to this procedure a loop which will drop the row policies and masking policies of the cloned database but I am running into some issues:
the 2 issues I have is :

I am unsure of the syntax for looping through cursors in snowflake
I am getting an error "Error: creating backup ZZ_BKP_STEWARDSHIP_20240531_1440522049: SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 46
Bind variable :v_clone_db_name not set."

Below is the code for the procedure:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DBMGT.DBADMIN.XXtest_SNF_DB_BACKUP("P_SOURCE_DB_NAME" VARCHAR(16777216))
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS '
DECLARE
    v_clone_db_name VARCHAR;
    v_sql VARCHAR;
    v_sql_loop VARCHAR;
    
    
    c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT ''ALTER ''|| REF_ENTITY_DOMAIN || '' '' || :v_clone_db_name || ''.'' ||REF_SCHEMA_NAME||''.''||REF_ENTITY_NAME||''  modify column ''||ref_column_name|| '' unset masking policy;'' AS sql_stmt from  SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.POLICY_REFERENCES where ref_database_name= upper(:p_source_db_name) ;



    
    c2 CURSOR FOR SELECT ''ALTER ''||REF_ENTITY_DOMAIN|| '' '' || :v_clone_db_name ||  ''.''||REF_SCHEMA_NAME||''.''||REF_ENTITY_NAME|| '' DROP ALL ROW ACCESS POLICIES;'' AS sql_stmt from  SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.POLICY_REFERENCES where ref_database_name= upper(:p_source_db_name) and ref_column_name is null;

    
BEGIN
    -- Check if the source database exists
    IF (NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM "SNOWFLAKE"."INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."DATABASES"
        WHERE DATABASE_NAME = upper(:p_source_db_name)
    ) )THEN
        RETURN ''Source database does not exist'';
    END IF;

    -- Generate a unique clone database name with timestamp as prefix and ''_BKP'' as suffix
    v_clone_db_name := ''ZZ_BKP_'' || P_SOURCE_DB_NAME || ''_'' || TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), ''YYYYMMDD_HH24MISS'');
    
    -- Create the SQL statement to clone the database
    v_sql := ''CREATE DATABASE "'' || v_clone_db_name || ''" CLONE "'' || P_SOURCE_DB_NAME || ''"''; 

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;



    OPEN c1;

    
    --Execute the output of the following to drop masking pols

    FOR row_variable IN c1 DO
    v_sql_loop := (row_variable.value);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql_loop;
    END FOR;

    CLOSE c1;


   OPEN c2;

    
    --Execute the output of the following to drop masking pols
     
     FOR row_variable IN c2 DO
    v_sql_loop := (row_variable.value);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql_loop;
    END FOR;

    ClOSE c2;
    
    
    

    -- Log the backup status
    INSERT INTO DBMGT.DBADMIN.XXX_BKP_DBLOGS (LOG_MESSAGE, action, status)
    VALUES (''created backup '' || :v_clone_db_name, ''Backup'',''Success'');

    RETURN ''Backup successful'';
    
            
    exception when other then
    LET LINE := SQLCODE || '': '' || SQLERRM;


INSERT INTO DBMGT.DBADMIN.XXX_BKP_DBLOGS (LOG_MESSAGE, action, status)
    VALUES (''Error: creating backup '' || :v_clone_db_name || :LINE , ''Backup'',''Failed'');

    
     RETURN ''Backup unsuccessful'';
     
             
END;
';

The parts I am most unsure about how I am declaring the cursors and variables, and also how I am looping through the cursors (from 'open c1' to 'close c2')
Would really appreciate any help to get me in the right direction with this :)
I have tried the above, using snowflake documentation as a guide for defining the cursors and looping through them to execute dropping the masking policies and row policies.
All other parts of the code worked before trying to drop the masking policies and row policies (i.e.I only have errors with the parts of the code to do with the cursors c1 and c2)

you only need to use the bind variable syntax (colon in front of the variable name) where the SQL statement is being executed (like the INSERT statements at the end of your code). Where they are in a string, like in your cursor definitions, you just use the variable name, no colon

I dropped colons from the variables in the part of the script where I defined the Cursors, but now I am getting an error "Error creating backup ZZ_BKP_STEWARDSHIP_20240605_055435904: SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 46 invalid identifier 'V_CLONE_DB_NAME'"
